# How to preview Camera in Raspberry in Android Things?

Tags: android, raspberry-pi3, android-things

I have installed Android Things in Raspberry 3. I have connected Camera and display. How can I show preview it?

Comment: See if your camera is recognized by the `android.hardware.Camera` or `android.hardware.camera2.*` APIs. If it is, use them. If it is not, contact the camera manufacturer for instructions.

Comment: Just add code in onPictureTaken() method---   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "setting clicked image to ImageView");
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            });

Answer (score 2):

Check the code provided by Google in the [dorbell](https://github.com/androidthings/doorbell) example. Especially the [DoorbellCamera](https://github.com/androidthings/doorbell/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/androidthings/doorbell/DoorbellCamera.java) class.

Comment: I used that same example. I have to use camera preview as well as use Mobile Vision. But both the things want to start the camera. Which is a big problem

Comment: I might be wrong but Camera Preview on the RPI3 is not possible right now because of that. 

"Graphics: Hardware graphics acceleration is not currently enabled."
[Check this link](https://developer.android.com/things/preview/releases.html)